# Annoying redirection

Tags: settings

Every time I phone gets turned off of or goes to sleep, after turning it back on and typing in my password I get instantly taken to the play store and some other useless website ad. Is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

Comment: What phone?  Do you have an app that has lockscreen ads?

Answer (score 0):

Are your WiFi or data connections enabling even after you've disabled them?
If so, or even not so, your phone is probably hit by malwares/adwares that redirect you to some infected web site or to a specific Google play app's page.

You need to check your app list and see if there are some unusual apps then uninstall them (some  apps may need root access and BusyBox installed) either by system apps removers (apk) or from adb shell

Comment: I remember having an app that said it needs busy box and I also downloaded king root    and rooted my phone. Is that bad?

Comment: what app? Chinese root apps such as Kongroot installs adwares. you have to remove them.

Comment: Its an app called "lucky patcher" that says it requires busybox and I have kingroot

Comment: Lucky patcher is used gor hacking apps, games allowing you to get free in app purchases, Install modded play store, remove ads and License verification from android apps and games, at least the original version, because there are many other versions of the app which cannot be guaranteed free of malwares. Did you check your app list yet?

Comment: KingRoot installs adwares on phones.